# difference between flush and close function in case of filewriter in java

Tags: java, io

I need to know what is exact difference between flush and close function in Java?

And When the data is dumped into a file during writing of file?

Please provide one example

Answer (score 63, accepted):

flush() writes the content of the buffer to the destination and makes the buffer empty for further data to store but it does not closes the stream permanently. That means you can still write some more data to the stream.

But close() closes the stream permanently. If you want to write some data further, then you have to reopen the stream again and append the data with the existing ones.

Comment: When using BufferedWriter (or BufferedReader) we don't have to worry about flush() - the BufferedWriter flushes internally while "write()" whenever the buffer is full.

Comment: But at the end __if the buffer is not empty neither full__, and we want to write that final part into the disk(which is almost always desired), __we have to `flush()` it explicitly/manually__, which is very necessary.

Comment: @WesternGun No: Invoking `flush()` explicitely is not required for a BufferedWriter, as long as you `close()` the writer. `close()` executes a flush itself.

Answer (score 79):

`flush()` *just* makes sure that any buffered data is written to disk (in this case - more generally, flushed through whatever IO channel you're using). You can still write to the stream (or writer) afterwards.

`close()` flushes the data *and indicates that there isn't any more data*. It closes any file handles, sockets or whatever. You then can't write to the stream (or writer) any more.

Note that without calls to `flush()` data *can* still be written to the IO channel in question - it's just that some data *might* be buffered.

`close()` generally calls `flush()` as well, but it's recently been pointed out to me that in some JDK implementations, any exceptions thrown by flushing as part of closing are swallowed :(

Comment: flush() is enough ? or we should call close after flush ?
If I want to call flush

Answer (score 6):

`flush()` flushes content of buffer to destination.And you can write something again into the stream.`close()` flushes content to destination and closes the stream. After `close()` you can't write anything anymore.

Comment: Jon Skeet wrote 15 seconds earlier ))

Answer (score 3):

**`flush()`** :To flush output stream, use `void flush()` method of `DataOutputStream` class. This method internally calls `flush()` method of underlying `OutputStream` class which forces any buffered output bytes to be written in the stream.

**`close()`** :It generally close the Stream,connection,socket.

See [`flush` and `close` example](http://www.java-examples.com/flush-output-stream)

Comment: But will it immediately flush the data or content in the file whenever it encounters there is some data to be written in file?

Comment: No,It doesn't immediately flush the data.It force the output bytes to write data in stream.when you call close method then it fulshes data and indicate there is no any more data.

Answer (score 0):

The flush method will flush all the content in the streams to the destination. After writing something, it may not be at the destination.

The close method will close the streams and will do the flush before closing.

The following is I got from [Oracle Java I/O tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html).

> To flush a stream manually, invoke its flush method. The flush method is valid on any output stream, but has no effect unless the stream is buffered.

If you only use fileWriter without buffer, using flush has no effect. The only thing you need to do is close the streams. And the close method will flush the streams before closing them.

If I understand correctly, it seems that as long as we remember to close the streams, we are good.