# App writing to file

Tags: java, android, file

I've an app that is writing data to a file. The first time I run it, it goes grand and writes 1000s of values to the file. Then I close the app using this code

```
finish();
System.exit(0);
```

Which happens when I hit the stop button.

When I run it again after stopping, say in a few minutes, it only writes a few values to a new file, over the same time frame.

Here is the code I use to write to the file:

```
public void write(String message) {

    try {
        if (out == null) {
            FileWriter datawriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            out = new BufferedWriter(datawriter);
            //out.write("X Value, Y Value, Z Value \n");
        }
        if (file.exists()) {
            out.append(message);
            out.flush();    
        }
```

Any insight into why this is happening would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Android supports `FileWriter`?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What values is it writing? Where do they come from? Are you sure there should be thousands?

Comment: @AndrewThompson it should do, it writes the values I'm expecting and in the region i need them

Comment: @iamnotmaynard its writing accelerometer values from the phones

Comment: Did you miss the part about the SSCCE?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm reading it right now, but I'm not sure what you want. The code that my problem is with is there, the app should be writing the message(gathered in other methods which are working) to the file. The problem is with the other runnings of the app after the first.

Comment: *"gathered in other methods which are working"*  Famous last words..

Comment: @AndrewThompson they always are :P But in this case, they are as they displaying the values on screen ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On finishing do `out.close()`. It probably is a system deteriorating.

Comment: instead of `finish(); System.exit(0);` ?

Comment: No, before. What finish does I do not know.

Comment: It doesn't work, out.close needs a class or variable. I should point out that I'm closing the app in a different class and that the file writing is happening in another class.

Comment: Then do `out.close(); out = null;` instead of `out.flush();`. In fact better remove the condition `if (file.exists())` as the open code would have thrown an exception otherwise.

Comment: What exception would it throw? It hasn't thrown any exception with the first test runs. The flush is needed because it's constantly writing to the file, closing it would be unefficient as it would need to be reopened again.

Comment: This is the question that I read about it http://stackoverflow.com/a/9272608/1383281

Comment: Inefficient, but *not* closing is a possible leak on system level.

Comment: Which would probably be causing the problem, now it makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call

```
System.exit(0);
```

Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon) to know why.

Also, you shouldn't need to call `flush()`, but just `close()` when you're done, before your call to `finish()`.

Try with this code:

```
public void write(String message) {
    try {
        if (out == null) {
            FileWriter datawriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
            out = new BufferedWriter(datawriter);
        }
        out.append(message);
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to call that to flush the buffer, least thats what I thought it is needed for. It was crashing when I had close and not flush before. Reading that post I should just leave it as `finish();` ?