# I couldn't write a string in a txt

Tags: java

I try to read and write a file using java. I have tried my code, but it's not work properly.

See below is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class UptimeSample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            double oldTime=0;
            BufferedReader read=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/eGurkha/agent/sample/UptimeRecord.txt"));
            String oldline=read.readLine();
            if(oldline == null)
            {
                System.out.println("New Entry ::::");
                Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\eGurkha\\lib\\vmgfiles\\win\\VmgUptimeTest.exe");
                BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line=rd.readLine();
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] word=line.split("=");
                FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter("C:/eGurkha/agent/sample/UptimeRecord.txt");
                fileWriter.write(word[1]);
                System.out.println("New System Time is :"+word[1]);
                System.out.println("String Written");
            }
            else
            {
                oldTime=Double.parseDouble(oldline);
                Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\eGurkha\\lib\\vmgfiles\\win\\VmgUptimeTest.exe");
                BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                String line=rd.readLine();
                String[] word=line.split("=");
                FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter("C:/eGurkha/agent/sample/UptimeRecord.txt");
                fileWriter.write(word[1]);
                System.out.println("New System Time is :"+word[1]);
                System.out.println("String Written");
                double crrTime=Double.parseDouble(word[1]);
                double diffTime=crrTime-oldTime;
                System.out.println("Difference Time is :"+diffTime);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

It gives the following Output:

```
New Entry ::::
System=13042.827175
New System Time is :13042.827175
String Written
```

The output is correct, but the problem is when I open the "UptimeRecord.txt" file, the file is empty. I couldn't write in that file.

Comment: use `line.split("\\=")` and then at last use `filewrite.close()`

Comment: I would suggest to close filewriter in finally block and also take out common code from if-else block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close your FileWriter

```
fileWriter.close();
```

As Suggested by JoeBlade, this should be done in a finally block :

```
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (fileWriter != null) {
        fileWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would expand the answer with the suggestion to do it in a finally block, since the author has a try / catch in place.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `.flush()` and `.close()` the `FileWriter`. When flushig a `FileWriter`, the data is sent to its destination. You could also consider using a `BufferedFileWriter`, which takes care of the flushing and closing for you.

See also: [difference between flush and close function in case of filewriter in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272585/difference-between-flush-and-close-function-in-case-of-filewriter-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

File must be close [file.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#close())

```
fileWriter.close();
```