# Using DOM parser to output an XML file to a text file?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

Alright before anyone asks me why I use DOM parser instead of SAX for XML files, the reason is simple. I feel that DOM is easier to use rather than SAX because my XML files are usually very small in size so it doesn't require much memory to parse it through a SAX, rather than  SAX being an event based XML Parser and it parses XML file step by step which is suitable for large XML Files.

So now I have this sample XML file right here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schedule id="backup" duration="86400">
<datapoint time="0" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="8" concurrencynoise="1" interval="300" intervalnoise="300"/> <!-- 12am -->
<datapoint time="7200" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="8" concurrencynoise="1" interval="300" intervalnoise="300"/> <!-- 2am -->
<datapoint time="7201" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="0" concurrencynoise="0" interval="300" intervalnoise="300"/> <!-- 2:00:01am -->
<datapoint time="86399" speed="1" speednoise=".5" concurrency="0" concurrencynoise="0" interval="10" intervalnoise="0"/>  <!-- 11:59:59pm -->
</schedule>
```

My code :

```
 try {
        //this is the text file that i want to write into
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("new_backup.txt"));
        //this is the file that i want to read from
        File fXmlFile = new File("backup.xml");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("datapoint");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                System.out.println("Time : " + eElement.getAttribute("time"));
                System.out.println("Speed : " + eElement.getAttribute("speed"));
                System.out.println("SpeedNoise : " + eElement.getAttribute("speednoise"));
                System.out.println("Concurrency : " + eElement.getAttribute("concurrency"));
                System.out.println("ConcurrencyNiose : " + eElement.getAttribute("concurrencynoise"));
                System.out.println("Interval : " + eElement.getAttribute("interval"));
                System.out.println("IntervalNoise : " + eElement.getAttribute("intervalnoise"));
                if (eElement.hasChildNodes()) {
                    NodeList nl = node.getChildNodes();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++) {
                        Node nd = nl.item(j);
                        String name = nd.getTextContent();
                        if (name != null && !name.trim().equals("")) {
                            System.out.print(name.trim() + ",");
                            //System.out.print(" ");
                            writer.write(nd.getTextContent().trim() + " ");
                        }

                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    writer.write("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement) {
    NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
}
```

`Output: An empty text file.`

What am I doing wrong here? Isn't DOM parser supposed to work on the nodes of the XML file in which the element is "datapoint" ? And when I print out the output into system console it returns me my result but however when I put it in a text file it is empty. I'm new to this kind of parser and I am doing this for a project in school.

```
Console Output: Time : 0
Speed : 1
SpeedNoise : .5
Concurrency : 8
ConcurrencyNiose : 1
Interval : 300
IntervalNoise : 300
Time : 7200
Speed : 1
SpeedNoise : .5
Concurrency : 8
ConcurrencyNiose : 1
Interval : 300
IntervalNoise : 300
Time : 7201
Speed : 1
SpeedNoise : .5
Concurrency : 0
ConcurrencyNiose : 0
Interval : 300
IntervalNoise : 300
Time : 86399
Speed : 1
SpeedNoise : .5
Concurrency : 0
ConcurrencyNiose : 0
Interval : 10
IntervalNoise : 0
```

But it doesn't save into the text file as I wanted to.

Comment: A parser is for *reading*.

Comment: Is there any way to use another code to save the output it into a text file? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Try replacing all uses of `getTextContent()` with `getNodeValue()`.  "Text content" generally refers to the inner contents of elements, not the values of attributes.

Comment: @VGR doesn't work still :(

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `for` loop is iterating the `<datapoint>` elements. The elements don't have any child nodes (`<datapoint/>` is an empty element), so the `if` statement is never entered, which means nothing to ever written to the `writer`.

You probably meant to iterate the *attributes* for your data point elements. Since attribute order may be arbitrary, iteration is not optimal, so you should get them by name, just like you're doing in the print statements.

Comment: But even if I did it wouldn't change anything because this "datapoint" element is being used to get the attributes from the file and output it in console. That's from what I understand sorry if I'm wrong i'm still relatively new to Java. :(

Comment: My second paragraph was referring to the *inner* iteration, not the outer loop.

Answer (score -2):

Please add `writer.flush();` right before line that says `writer.close();`

close() generally calls flush() as well but I always call `writer.flush();`.
The reason being that that in some JDK implementations, any exceptions thrown by flushing as part of closing are swallowed.  here is the relevant so thread: [difference between flush and close function in case of filewriter in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272585/difference-between-flush-and-close-function-in-case-of-filewriter-in-java) . Scroll down to @Jon Skeet answer

Comment: From the [documentation for the close() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close--): “Closes the stream, flushing it first.”  close() always implies flush().

Comment: @VGR would you reconsider the down vote as per updated comment?

Comment: Even in the JDK implementations Jon mentions, flush() is always called.