# Why does this gson function save a blank file?

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to create a java application and I have a question regarding a function inside the gson API. Why does this line of code generate an empty json file without any errors showing?

An example object that reproduces this issue:

```java
public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String occupation;

    public Employee(String name, String occupation) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

}
```

```java
//this refers to a simple java object that works with gson
gson.toJson(this, new FileWriter(new File("somefile.json")));
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: post little bit more code

Comment: Nope I don't have any errors. I will try to post more code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried with the HashMap object since OP did not have java object, but it should work fine with any other type of Java object.
it is working fine, the issue was with the writer, you need to flush the content and close the stream.

```
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a","b");
        map.put("c","d");
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("somefile.json"));
        gson.toJson(map, writer);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

File content:

```
{"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

Above code can be written as

```
try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("somefile.json"))) {
    gson.toJson(map, writer);
    writer.flush();
}
```

Here you do not need to explicitly close the stream, this code style is preferred over first one, and avoids any such bugs in the future.

Comment: `FileWriter` implements `AutoClosable`, so this would be better in a Try With Resources block

Comment: Nice :) I'm pretty sure that the `flush` can be omitted as well, since the implicitly called `close` method will flush before it closes the stream.

Comment: Yes, it can be but depends on implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9272606/2987755

Comment: "If you absolutely, positively HAVE to ensure it got written, call flush(). You can call flush anytime and you can call it as often as you like. If there's nothing to flush, the overhead is minimal." Ref: https://coderanch.com/t/442764/java/fileWriter-flush