# Nesting 'r' after opening a file in write mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-handling

so I had an exercise asking to write to a file (using newlines) and then open it in reading mode. I did exactly that and the console outputs the right result. What happened was that I tried to do it within the 'w' mode code block and the console outputs nothing.

For example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as wf:

    nicknames = ["Big Tuna", "Prison Mike", "Booster Seat"]

    wf.write('\n'.join(nicknames))

    with open('test.txt', 'r') as rf:

        print(rf.read())
```

I understand that the program only closes the file after the `with` statement, but I need clarification on my understanding of what's happening here.

So, what I understood so far is that the program first creates the `test.txt` file (test.txt did not exist in my file path) and then proceeds to convert and write the given contents into the `test.txt` file. After that, the nested `with` tries to open a file named `test.txt` in reading mode, but the console will not output anything because the program is trying to open a file that is already opened, that's why it cannot read into an already opened file.

Please correct me if I'm misunderstood the above because I am unsure whether or not I've understood it correctly, thank you.

Comment: What's the use case of reading a newly-created file that you just wrote into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s not what’s happening. Unix systems, at least, will happily let you open a file multiple times.

However, Python’s IO is buffered by default. You need to *flush* the data you’ve written out to the file before you can read the data from it. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.flush for more information about this. (Summary: put `wf.flush()` after the `wf.write(…)` call and before attempting to read from it.

Comment: Probably worth reiterating that files are flushed on close, so the 'right' solution is to unindent the second `with`.

Comment: Agreed. In many years of Python, I’ve never, not once, opened a file for reading while it was still open for writing. I mean, I could contrive a scenario where I’d want to, but that hasn’t actually happened in practice yet. But if you absolutely must, for some reason I’ve never experienced, then flush your buffers first.

Comment: I am not aware of this `.flush()` method, so thank you for that. This is what I understood so far about this flush method, so basically, whenever I 'write' to a file, the data that are written to the file still remain, and for Python to read that file, the file should not contain 'data' in it? Sorry, I'm a little confused about this.

Comment: @RoyalFrog. Generally the stuff you write to a file sits in a buffer in RAM until you have ~4KB or so of stuff, or manually call flush, or close the file. That's when the stuff gets written to disk. If you open the file for reading, it only knows what's on disk. It doesn't know about the unflushed write buffet.

Comment: @KirkStrauser. I'm proud to say that I once opened a file in `r+` mode.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ohh I see now, the last part really clears that up as to why didn't the program outputs anything. I was also searching about the differences of `flush()` and `close()`, it seems like they `close()` functions similarly to `flush()` except the "closing the stream permanently when using `close()'. 

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272585/difference-between-flush-and-close-function-in-case-of-filewriter-in-java/9272704

Comment: @RoyalFrog. Flushing just dumps what you have to disk. Closing flushes first, then cleans up all the system references to the file. It basically ends your session with it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have, too! It involved a lot of `seek`ing around, IIRC. What I _haven't_ done is have both a `w` handle and a `r` handle open to the same file at the same time in the same process.

Comment: @KirkStrauser. Can't say I've ever tried that myself either. Sounds like a fun thing to do if you like surprises though.